# NSUnknownKeyException? statusBarManager

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode14

I'm getting this error whenever I run my app and then the app crashes.

```
Thread 1: "[<UIApplication 0x161704080> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key statusBarManager."
```

I've tried googling this and it seems people have had the problem before, but either I don't understand the solution whatsoever, or the solution they present doesn't work for me. Any ideas?

Also here are the files for the project in google drive https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1TzQgwC_CgEC_wertNmyF0ZrL_vKFgILS?usp=sharing

Comment: Without knowing anything about your app, this is impossible to debug here, and it makes it somewhat unlikely that someone will have a solution. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: I added the project files, hope that helps.

Comment: You are unlikely to get help here asking someone to download a full project from an unknown source. It is customary (and more likely to get you help) to include a [mre] in source code here, on SO.